# Why would both sides of an if statement appear to execute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, xaf

I found a scenario where both sides of an if statement execute. Why?

I did not think that this was possible in C#.

The problem occurs the second time I run an XAF EF Code First solution. After I have deleted the .mdf and _log.ldf files originally created.

When I step through the code the !database.Exists statement evaluates as true.

Then when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> ( at the point commented in the code snippet after establishing the database does not exist ) the next step I see in the debugger is in the catch statement.

The code snippet is from the Dev Express .pdb file and unfortunately the catch statement does not give me a way to inspect the error message.

```
protected virtual DatabaseSchemaState CheckDatabaseSchemaCompatibilityCore(Object context) 
{
    DatabaseSchemaState result = DatabaseSchemaState.SchemaExists;
    if(context is DbContext) 
    {
        Database database = ((DbContext)context).Database;
        if(!database.Exists()) 
        {
            // If I press F11 here
            result = DatabaseSchemaState.DatabaseMissing;  
        }
        else 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (!database.CompatibleWithModel(false)) 
                {
                    result = DatabaseSchemaState.SchemaRequiresUpdate;
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                // the next step is here
                result = DatabaseSchemaState.SchemaRequiresUpdate;  
            }
        }
    }

    // etc
}
```

The thread window shows both steps are on the same thread.

When I press <kbd>F11</kbd> at line 318, after some seconds the next step I see highlighted is line 327

[image: the second step]

The call stack at the exception is

```
DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFObjectSpaceProvider.CheckDatabaseSchemaCompatibilityCore(object context) Line 327 C#
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFObjectSpaceProvider.CreateObjectContext(System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.IDisposable> disposableObjects) Line 182 + 0xc bytes  C#
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFObjectSpaceProvider.Init(System.Type contextType, DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.ITypesInfo typesInfo, DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFTypeInfoSource typeInfoSource, System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, string connectionString, string metadataLocations, string providerName) Line 116 + 0xd bytes   C#
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFObjectSpaceProvider.EFObjectSpaceProvider(System.Type contextType, DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.ITypesInfo typesInfo, DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFTypeInfoSource typeInfoSource, string connectionString, string metadataLocations, string providerName) Line 209 + 0x15 bytes C#
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFObjectSpaceProvider.EFObjectSpaceProvider(System.Type contextType, DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.ITypesInfo typesInfo, DevExpress.ExpressApp.EF.EFTypeInfoSource typeInfoSource, string connectionString) Line 215 + 0x17 bytes    C#
        DXApplicationkg1.Win.exe!DXApplicationkg1.Win.DXApplicationkg1WindowsFormsApplication.CreateDefaultObjectSpaceProvider(DevExpress.ExpressApp.CreateCustomObjectSpaceProviderEventArgs args) Line 35 + 0x66 bytes    C#
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.XafApplication.CreateObjectSpaceProviders(string connectionString) Line 294 + 0xc bytes   C#
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.v18.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.XafApplication.Setup() Line 1543 + 0x1e bytes C#
        DXApplicationkg1.Win.exe!DXApplicationkg1.Win.Program.Main() Line 45 + 0xa bytes    C#
```

The Optimize Code button on the build tab is not checked.

The code is from the DevExpress .pdb files

[Update]
After enabling the break exception I can see

[image: this exception]

Indicating that the login failed for user.

```
+       $exception  {System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "DXApplicationkg1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MYCOMPUTER\kirst'.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()} System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException}
```

[Update]

Karol commented

> If both "sides" of IF statement are executed, it means that you
>   executed method twice.

However If I put a break at line 314 it is only reached once.

I should mention I am running Windows 10 1809

I have asked a related question at [Dev Express](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T700395/troubleshooting)

Comment: Why do you think both side of an if statement are executing?

Comment: because the catch is inside the else statement.

Comment: your break point is in the parent if statement, Just because a context is a DBContext doesn't mean the Db Exists

Comment: I think you are confused about what the user interface elements you've taken a screenshot of mean. Can you explain to us what you believe each of those elements means, and then we can tell you where you are wrong.

Comment: Is this optimized code? Such things can happen in this case.

Comment: Also, you've said "both sides of the if" but there are two ifs in your code snippet. Which one do you mean by "the if"? I assume the innermost one, correct?

Comment: You gave a stack trace that says that the exception was thrown on line 327, but have not said which line in your screenshot was line 327. Which one was it?

Comment: You also haven't said what the type of the exception is. **Make it easier on us to help you**.  You're leaving out all sorts of details that might be important.

Comment: @johnny I explain in the text that I know the db does not exist because I deleted it.

Comment: @EricLippert I mean the outer if.

Comment: If you know the db doesn't exist, then it should be going into the other path.  If you see the debugger at the wrong line chances are your source mismatches the dll e.g your attempting to debug an optimized assembly

Comment: But you haven't shown us the alternative of the outer `if`, nor said why it is that you think that the alternative of the outer `if` is the one that is executing. This question is very confusing. By the "outermost" `if`, you mean the second of the three `if`s, right?

Comment: @EricLippert Apologies, The (!database.exists()  statement.  I updated the question to show line numbers. After line 318 then next I see executed in the debugger is line 327

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks. I updated the question to show that the Optimised code on the build tab is not checked.

Comment: @EricLippert Is there a way I can get the exception text when the catch statement does not mention the exception?

Comment: You're in the debugger; examine the exception in the debugger. If you do not know how to debug an exception, then **learn how to do that before you ask any more questions about it**.  The introductory documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger To look specifically at the exception, add `$exception` to your watch window, or use the exception helper.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables for more on how to use the watch window effectively.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks. I updated the question to show the exception.

Comment: If both "sides" of IF statement are executed, it means that you executed method twice.

Comment: @Karol I updated the question to show that the method is not being called recursively.

Comment: @jonskeet is what I am experiencing possible?

Comment: @KirstenGreed: FYI there's no "bat signal" on Stack Overflow; Jon will not get a notification that you've mentioned him in a comment unless he has already commented on the post.

Comment: But to answer your question: that is a very strange question to ask. **Everything that you experience is possible, provided that your interpretation of your experience is correlated to reality.** We never experience impossible things unless we have been fooled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs explain here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/jit-optimization-and-debugging?view=vs-2017) to check the 'Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)' option in the debugging options.

When I did that only the **else** part if the if statement was executed in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you Gosha at Dev Express for pointing this out. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T700395/troubleshooting